# Ajuda com na compreensão de código de autômato celular

Tags: c, bitwise, autômatos

Gostaria que vocês me ajudassem a entender um código para cálculo e apresentação de autômatos celulares que encontrei na internet. O código em questão é o seguinte:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void PrintfVetor(char vetor[], char tamanho);
void CopiaVetor(char vetor_in[], char vetor_out[], int tamanho);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char *L_ant, *L_atu;
    int n, k, bit;
    int N, linhas, regra;
/* Obtem dados de entrada */
    printf("Digite o comprimento da linha: ");
    scanf("%d", &N);
    printf("Digite o numero de linhas: ");
    scanf("%d", &linhas);
    printf("Digite a regra a ser utilizada (0 a 255): ");
    scanf("%d", &regra);
/* Aloca espaco para o vetor atual e o anterior */     
    L_ant = (char*) malloc(N*sizeof(char));
    L_atu = (char*) malloc(N*sizeof(char));
/* Criacao da linha inicial */
/* Preenche a linha inicial com zeros */
    for(n=0; n<N; n++)
            L_ant[n] = 0;
/* Insere o valor 1 na posicao do meio da linha inicial */
    L_ant[N/2] = 1;
/* Define que na linha atual, a primeira posicao e a ultima serao sempre 
iguais a 0 */
    L_atu[0] = L_atu[N-1] = 0;
/* Escreve a linha inicial na tela */
    PrintfVetor(L_ant, N);
/* Percorre as próximas linhas */
    for(k=2; k<=linhas; k++)
    {
/* Percorre cada posicao da linha atual, exceto a primeira e a ultima 
posicoes */
            for(n=1; n<N-1; n++)
            {
                    /* Obtem a regra para a posicao atual, e atualiza essa 
posicao na linha atual */
                    bit = L_ant[n-1]*4+L_ant[n]*2+L_ant[n+1];
                    L_atu[n] = (regra&(1<<bit))!=0;
            }
/* Escreve a linha atual na tela */
            PrintfVetor(L_ant, N);
/* Atualiza a linha anterior */
            CopiaVetor(L_atu, L_ant, N);
    }
/* Libera a memoria dinamica das linhas */
    free(L_ant);
    free(L_atu);
    return 0;
}

void PrintfVetor(char vetor[], char tamanho)
{
    int n;
    for(n=0; n<tamanho; n++)
            printf("%d ", vetor[n]);
    puts("");
}

void CopiaVetor(char vetor_in[], char vetor_out[], int tamanho)
{
    int n;
    for(n=0; n<tamanho; n++)
            vetor_out[n] = vetor_in[n];
}`
```

O programa em si eu entendi, mas eu não consigo entender o cálculo que é feito nesta parte aqui:

```
bit = L_ant[n-1]*4+L_ant[n]*2+L_ant[n+1];
L_atu[n] = (regra&(1<<bit))!=0;
```

Se puderem me explicar ficarei muito agradecido.

*código retirado do blog: http://progcmaismais.blogspot.com/2011/01/codigo-em-c-automatos-celulares.html*

Answer (score 2):

Ele codificou bit a bit os "vizinhos".

No bit 2 (valor 4), colocou o vizinho à esquerda:

```
4*L_ant[n-1]
```

No bit 1 (valor 2), colocou o valor atual:

```
2*L_ant[n]
```

Já no bit 0 (valor 1), colocou o vizinho à direita:

```
L_ant[n+1]
```

Assim, caso se obtivesse `6 = 110`, sabemos que os vizinhos vivos são o da posição atual e o da direita.

Eu, particularmente, já que está fazendo apenas operações de bits, ficaria nelas:

```
 bit = L_ant[n-1]<<2 | L_ant[n]<<1 | L_ant[n+1]
```

Após obter esse número, ele faz `2^bit` através do deslocamento de bits: `1<<bit`. Portanto, o número anterior 6 seria transformado em 64 após essa operação.

Fazer `regra & (1<<bit)` é perguntar se, dentro das informações lidas em `regra`, uma delas coincide com a disposição da vizinhança. Por exemplo, se eu fornece `regra == 192`, haveria *match* para o meu 64. Mas isso não é mais verdade com `regra == 180`, já que esse não contém mesmo o 64.

A atribuição em `L_atu[n]` indica que essa verificação da `regra` funciona para saber se o elemento de índice `n` vai permanecer vivo na próxima rodada.

Ele faz a atribuição da seguinte maneira para garantir que o valor em `L_atu[n]` seja sempre 1 ou 0:

```
L_atu[n] = (regra & (1<<bit)) != 0
```

Se não tivesse esse `!= 0`, seria armazenado em `L_atu[n]` o valor `1<<bit`, desde que esse valor esteja dentro de `regra`.